# resetItems PyQt - how to reload script

Tags: python, linux, pyqt

This is only the part of my script. I can't reload my script (without stopping it) when data in file.txt changed.

```
class StockListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
        def __init__(self, stockdata = [], parent = None):
            QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
            self.stockdata = stockdata
            self.file_check = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(['/home/user/Desktop/file.txt'])
            self.file_check.fileChanged.connect(self.resetItems)

        def getItems(self):
           return stockdata

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
        def resetItems(self, path):
           self.beginResetModel()
           self.stockdata = self.stockdata    #without this and next line I have the same
           self.endResetModel()          #error

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle("plastique")

        tableView = QtGui.QTableView()      
        tableView.show()

        a = os.popen("cat /home/user/Desktop/file.txt")
        a = a.read()
        time_variable = QtCore.QString("%s"%a)

        model = StockListModel([time_variable])

        tableView.setModel(model)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this script and I update file I get an error:
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'beginResetModel'

What should I change to refresh data?

Comment: Unless you have defined it globally, the stockdata variable doesn't exist outside of the contructor, yet you are attempting to use it in both the getItems and resetItems functions. Perhaps you mean self.stockdata?

Comment: Yes, I mean self.stockdata in getItems but still it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the `fileChanged` signal of your `QFileSystemWatcher` [emits a string](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html#fileChanged), which is being received by `resetItems()`, which is expecting an instance of `StockListModel`. The `self` reference doesn't get passed because `file_check` has been defined to be static and is not bound to a particular instance.

Try moving `file_check` into the constructor as an instance variable and modifying `resetItems()` to accept the string parameter emitted by `fileChanged`.

**EDIT**: Added code for clarity

Constructor:

```
    def __init__(self, stockdata = [], parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.stockdata = stockdata
        self.file_check = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(['/home/user/Desktop/file.txt'])
        self.file_check.fileChanged.connect(self.resetItems)
```

resetItems:

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def resetItems(self, path):
        self.beginResetModel()
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, just define it in the constructor like that. No need to pass it in as a parameter

Comment: file_check = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher([’/home/user/Desktop/plik.txt’])
file_check only checks if file was changed if was:

file_check.fileChanged.connect(resetItems)
it sends signal to ‘resetItems’ and ‘resetItems’ should reload data, true?

Comment: file_check will fire the fileChanged signal if any of the files it is watching changes. The string parameter is sends is the path of the file that changed. What you do with this depends on what you are trying to achieve. What is resetItems supposed to do? I suspect you probably want to change the line self.stockdata = stockdata to reload the contents of the file that has just changed and update the model

Comment: yep, I want to change content of the cell (reload data). That's why I use resetItems which doesn't work because of 'string'

Comment: file_check works correct, I only need to modify resetItems - no idea

Comment: You just need to add the additional parameter - def resetItems(self, path)

Comment: Right now I saw your code above. I edited constructor the same like you and I also made some changes in resetItems and:
AttributeError: 'StockListModel' object has no attribute 'beginResetModel' ;]

Comment: Could you update your post to show the changes? I don't see any reason why you should get an error.

Comment: I'm going to assume you just forgot to remove the old definition of file_check from your code above. The rest looks ok. I wasn't able to reproduce the error you're getting running similar code. Maybe you could upload your full code to something like pastebin? Also, the way you have edited your post now leaves the code inconsistent with your original question/problem. You should modify it to make this clear. If you have new questions you should consider asking them in a new post.

Comment: I forgot to remove "old" file_check but after removal I have got the same error. Do you suggest it works for you?

Comment: Problem moved to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410025/beginresetmodel-attributeerror-stocklistmodel

Comment: I created this modified version of your code and it updates the table as the file changes without error http://pastebin.com/nzhkUe3U

Comment: Thank you for that but it doesn't solve my problem. Is it written under c++ ? one of the difference is that I a read content of the file (a = os.popen) where you create variable 'file'. I need to keep it because there will be more files (file.txt) and each contain sth different.

Comment: I realise you can't use my code directly, but it runs without the error you stated. The parts that I changed should have no effect on the outcome. Can you run it without getting any errors?

Comment: when I put in resetItems, only 'print self.path' and 'print self.stockdata' I see directory and not changed 'stockdata'. without errors but view is not updated.

Comment: That is what I would expect to see. With only those lines present there is nothing that modifies self.stockdata.

Comment: Your code runs without error on my machine after fixing the line self.stocdata = stockdata in resetItems. Are you running the latest version of PyQt? I'm not sure I can help with the problem much further.

Comment: "fixing line", do you mean self.stockdata = stockdata, I wrote without 'k' ?. If it works for you perhaps there is some problem with my linux.

Comment: python 2.6.6, PyQt4-4.6.2-9.el6.x86_64

Comment: I changed it to self.stockdata = self.stockdata since stockdata doesn't exist at that scope like I explained before. This is obviously useless but I just wanted to get the code running. How did you install PyQt? I know some distros like Ubuntu don't always offer the latest software versions through the default repositories. Perhaps you could try building the latest version from source yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure your Python version will make a difference, I would look at PyQt. The latest version is 4.11.

Comment: Under Ubuntu (updated) I neither get this error nor data is reloading. No idea what's going on and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Answer is under this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410025/beginresetmodel-doesnt-work