# beginResetModel() - doesn't work

Tags: python, linux, pyqt

When script is running I am changing content of the file.
On centos I have got error like that:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute
>   'beginResetModel'

On Ubuntu I don't have any error but the srcipt is not reloading the data.
Could it be related to beginResetModel in this case?

```
class StockListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
        def __init__(self, stockdata = [], parent = None):
            QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
            self.stockdata = stockdata
            self.file_check = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(['/home/user/Desktop/file.txt'])
            self.file_check.fileChanged.connect(self.resetItems)

        def getItems(self):
           return self.stockdata

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
        def resetItems(self, path):
           self.beginResetModel()
           self.stockdata = self.stockdata
           self.endResetModel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle("plastique")

        tableView = QtGui.QTableView()      
        tableView.show()

        file = open('/home/user/Desktop/file.txt')
        a = file.readline()             # ------> type STRING
        time_variable = QtCore.QString("%s"%a)

        model = StockListModel([time_variable])

        tableView.setModel(model)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the data when you reset the model:

```
self.stockdata = self.stockdata
```

This line needs to set `self.stockdata` to the updated value. Presumably you want to read in the changes from the file you are watching.

Comment: Do I have somehow repopulate stockdata in the constructor? like:
self.beginResetModel() \n
"repopulate somehow" \n
self.endResetModel()

Comment: No, the constructor is only called when you instantiate the object. After this the variable `stockdata` ceases to exist anywhere. You have simply stored a reference to its value in self.stockdata, which is a member of the `StockListModel` class. The `fileChanged` signal sends the path of the file that changed to your `resetItems` slot. You can use this read the changes from the file much like you are doing before you create the model.

Comment: Do you mean something like that ?: file = open("%s"%path) \n self.stockdata = file.readline()

Comment: Yes, although when you construct the model you are also converting `a` to `QString` (`time_variable`) and passing as a list `[time_variable]`. You should do exactly as you do the first time.

Comment: 'beginResetModel', 'end' and even 'self.stockdata' are not needed to reload data in script. thx for support.